# My background image keeps getting cut off at the bottom?

Tags: html, css

This isn't a duplicate, I've looked at similar questions and tried their solutions but nothing has worked. Half my image keeps getting cut off, other solutions have just centered it but it didn't strech across the page like I wanted it to without being distorted, any ideas on what's wrong?

***html***

```
<! DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mainPage.css"/>
</head>
<body>

<div id="header">


 </div>

 <div id="body">

 </div>

 <div id="footer">

 </div>

 </body>
 </html>
```

***css***

```
body{width: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
      }




#header{
    height:2300px;
    background-color:pink;
    background-image: url("http://horoscopespot.net/wp-  content/gallery/pisces/pisces-shadow.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;

    }
```

Comment: Please post code on JSFiddle where we can review and edit easily.

Comment: Why is the height set to 2300px ?

Comment: @kkaosninja I want it to fill the entire div, that's the size of the diV i want it to fill

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `margin-bottom:10px;` or  `padding-bottom:10px;`

Also, `background-size: 100% 100%` can help.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
background-size: cover;
```

Add this to your css.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in body tag

```
body
{
    background: url(http://horoscopespot.net/wp-content/gallery/pisces/pisces-shadow.jpg) no-repeat fixed top center;
}
```